# Estimating Required Data for NLP Classification Models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sampling, natural-language, text-mining

Are there general guidelines for how much data is required for natural language processing (NLP) classification models? I understand this may depend on the text quality, text length, how accurate the labels are, the event frequencies, the chosen algorithm, etc. Are there any general frameworks I can use to estimate how much data I would need? I'm going through an exercise of having data owners labeling their text data and i'd like to give them a recommendation for how much data they should label other than more is better.

Comment: This question seems clear to me and, since it is asking for "general guidelines" and acknowledges that there are complications, I don't think it is "too broad".

Comment: Even some literature on the tradeoff between data volume and model performance would be sufficient.

Comment: I was going to post a question strikingly similar to yours